# Sigma-algebra of a function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. I have been trying to prove that $\sigma(X)$ is a sigma-algebra on $\Omega$

I have the definition: $\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(A):A \in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$, but i cannot figure out how to proceed.

Is it correctly understood that A is a collection of sets? Or is it a sigma-algebra itself?

Comment: just use the set-theoretic properties of the image function, that is, that $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{x\in I}A_x)=\bigcup_{x\in I}f^{-1}(A_x)$ and so on, together with the monotone class theorem

Comment: So something like, $X^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) = \Omega, X^{-1}(A^C) = (X^{-1}(A))^C$ and $X^{-1}(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i) = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}(X^{-1}(A_i)$, we then get that $\sigma(X)$ is a sigma-algebra on $\Omega$ ?